# Why does the Scheduled Task “Regular Maintenance” change to enabled after being disabled

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task

Why does the "Regular Maintenance" scheduled task change from "Disabled" to "Enabled"?

The task was initially disabled when baking an AWS AMI. When the instance starts the task is disabled but 15 minutes after launch time the task changes to enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The status of the `Regular Maintenance` was being changed by the `Idle Maintenance` task. If I disabled the `Idle Maintenance` task immediately after startup the `Regular Maintenance` task status stayed as Disabled.

I tracked this down by using the `Get-ScheduledTaskIno` powershell command. Here's the change I observed.

Initial state of Idle Maintenance task:

```
TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\              Idle Maintenance                  Ready
\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\              Maintenance Configurator          Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\              Manual Maintenance                Ready
\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\              Regular Maintenance               Disabled

LastRunTime        : 10/30/2017 5:51:51 PM
LastTaskResult     : 0
NextRunTime        :
NumberOfMissedRuns : 0
TaskName           : Idle Maintenance
```

Indication Idle Maintenance had run and disabled Regular Maintenance task:

```
TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\              Idle Maintenance                  Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\              Maintenance Configurator          Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\              Manual Maintenance                Ready
\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\              Regular Maintenance               Ready

LastRunTime        : 11/22/2017 12:32:32 PM
LastTaskResult     : 0
NextRunTime        :
NumberOfMissedRuns : 0
TaskName           : Idle Maintenance
```